# Unable to change directory in command line

Tags: command-line, directory

I'm on c drive in command line
when I want to change the directory to D drive using :

```
cd /C D:\Riot Games
```

I get an error also with cmder

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using Windows, and you're using the standard cmd.exe for your command line, you should be quoting your path arguments for safety even though the docs will tell you it isn't strictly necessary since the command doesn't treat spaces as delimiters. The correct syntax is simply:

```
cd "D:\Riot Games"
```

There is also no `/C` argument to the `cd` command. You may have meant to use:

```
cd /D "D:\Riot Games"
```

to change the current drive in addition to changing the current directory, but whether that's actually necessary isn't clear from your example.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows CMD, you first need to switch to your other drive by just typing `D:`, then you can change directory by using the `cd "Riot Games"`